# Magento 2 Product Images Not Showing in detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-detail-page

http://madressingroom.com/black-and-white-varsity-jacket-10.html
Here is a link I have spent more than 1 week on it, please help me to get the solution. It's a Magento Molly Theme. Js file, not L

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
black-and-white-varsity-jacket-10.html:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1018
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getNodeData (scripts.js:87)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.js:117
    at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:70)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)
```

Here is an error shown in the console

Answer (score 1):

Could you please confirm if your magento version is 2.2.4?
You have error occured due to 
showCaption is empty.
showCaption require true|false value.
In your code 
`showCaption:,` 
look like this that why image is not load.

Please check following conditions.

1. Check your image has label present or not.
2. This error occured by overrides [YOUR THEME DESIGN DIRECTORY]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml file, it removes conditions from the gallery options

we need to modify the gallery.phtml that is overridden by the third party module or theme
use below code

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": {
                    "nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/nav") ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/loop"))): ?>
                        "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/loop") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"))): ?>
                        "keyboard": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/arrows"))): ?>
                        "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/arrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"))): ?>
                        "allowfullscreen": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/caption") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "width": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width') ?>",
                    "thumbwidth": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width') ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
                        "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
                        "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect") ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"))): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navtype") ?>",
                    "navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navdir") ?>"
                },
                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
                        "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
                        "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect") ?>"
                },
                "breakpoints": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change the mode from Production to Developer and then Check. It may helpful to fix error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below and see if it helps:

I had a similar issue and running `catalog:images:resize` solved my issue

Reindex the catalog: `indexer:reindex`

Clear & Flush Cache: `cache:flush` &  `cache:clean`